# Vagrant provider stuck to VMWare Workstation

Tags: vagrant, provider

After trying to use the VMWare Workstation providers for vagrant (which I now know requires a license), and switching back to VirtualBox, I have this problem :

```
$ ~/Homestead > vagrant up --provider=virtualbox
A valid license is required to run the Vagrant VMware
provider. Please visit http://www.vagrantup.com to purchase
a license. Once you purchase a license, you can install it
using `vagrant plugin license`.

Vagrant failed to initialize at a very early stage:
The plugins failed to load properly. The error message given is
shown below.

exit
```

I also tried exporting a default provider through `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER`, but to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

You dont need the equal (`=`) sign. just run

```
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

if you export the `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER` you can run the command with the option

```
fhenri@machine:~/project/ubuntu$ export VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER=virtualbox
fhenri@machine:~/project/ubuntu$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
```

Can you uninstall the vmware plugin to see if it has effect

```
vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vmware-fusion
```

Then run it again

can you confirm you have the same issue with any Vagrantfile ?

Comment: Tried the solution without the `=` sign, problem still occuring.

I already exported VirtualBox through `VAGRANT_DEFAULT_PROVIDER`.

Comment: can you try uninstall the plugin `vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vmware-fusion` see if it works, you can still reinstall if needed

Comment: `vagrant plugin uninstall vagrant-vmware-workstation` worked, thanks for the help.